# jQuery - Elements from new window undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this snippet of code that attempts to  create a new window, then alert the user to the html within the element that's id = "chatbody".

```
var w = window.open("window.html", "Messaging with " + $(this).text(), "height=250,width=400");
$(w.document).ready(function()
{
    alert($("#chatbody", w).html());
});
```

Here is the HTML for window.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main_style.css">
    <script src="http://layout.jquery-dev.net/lib/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="windowScript.js?n=10"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <table id = "chatboxFull">
    <tr><td id="chatbody">
        derp!
    </td></tr>
</table>

<br>
<p1>&nbsp;<input id="msg" type="text" />    &nbsp; 
<input id="send_msg" type="button" value="Send" /> </p1>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue I'm running into is that the box alerts "undefined" instead of the intended "derp!". If it's at all relevant, I am using Google Chrome. Does anyone have an insight into why this might be?

Comment: Don't put the opening bracket of a function on a new line. http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#core.semicolon

Comment: Huh. That's interesting. It does not fix my problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var w = window.open("window.html", "Messaging with " + $(this).text(), "height=250,width=400");
$(w).load(function()
{
    alert($("#chatbody", w.document).html());
});
```

Comment: As I understand it, without the w, it will not look at the child's ids.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I have edited my answer. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to alert the main window of the child window's #chatbody html, use `alert($("#chatbody", w.document).html());`

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery/ about the second parameter.

Comment: I tried this and sadly, it results in the same problem. All that does is narrow down the search for the chatbody element, I think.

Comment: It may have something to do with how you render out the chatBody's content in window.html. Is it just static text or are you adding it via Javascript?

Comment: It should just be static text, if you look at the html file.

Comment: No clue then. If you're still stuck, a test bed might help so that we can open a new window containing the actual page.